# Membership of which group grants a user access to udisksctl?

Tags: mount, permissions, users, udisks

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

There are multiple partitions on `/dev/sda`. `/dev/sda1` is where the system resides, `/dev/sda2, ..., /dev/sdaX` are NTFS partitions. There are two users, `admin` and `user`.

`admin` can mount any drive through the menu (the method involves `udiskctl`, IIRC). `user` was created as a standard user and can do it too. How can I prevent `user` from doing this?

`user` belongs to the following groups: `adm`,`audio`, `cdrom`, `dialout`, `dip`, `fax`, `floppy`, `fuse`, `plugdev`, `scanner`, `tape`, `video`.

Is `plugdev` the group I should remove it from, or maybe `fuse`?

Comment: Try them each out.  Part of the beauty of Linux is that if something breaks while experimenting, it is usually not permanent.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the user from the group `plugdev`. You can do it in the Users & Groups app.

Comment: Could you also add the exact command / method do do this so that a beginning Ubuntu user understands what you're saying as well?  **;-)**